# Creating a kendo dynamic wizard step and storing the each wizard step control values to a json object using ASP.NET Core

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-core

How to create dynamic kendo wizard step using asp.net core i need create the dynamic steps and i need to save the data on each step into Json format

---

```
<div class="container border border-danger py-5 mt-10">
    <div class="card card-custom border border-success">
        <div class="card-header">
            <div class="card-title">
                <label class="font-weight-bolder">Dynamic Wizard Steps</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body k-body py-5">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="row mt-10 mb-10">
                        <label class="col-12 font-weight-bolder mb-0">Please Enter The No. of Steps:</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-3">
                            <input id="wizardStepsNo" style="width:100%;" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-2">
                            <button class="k-button k-primary" type="button" id="stepsButton" onclick="createSteps()">Steps</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <from id="wizard" style="width:100%" novalidate></from>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```